# use of flow operators on objects

Tags: c++, class, ostream

I have a problem using the operators for injecting input / output flows on objects (operator <<)
I was actually writing code to make "cout <<" run on my objects and display their values; this is the following code, specifically a function and a class method, located in the same class file:

-function code:

```
ostream &operator<<( ostream &flux, Duree const& duree)
{
duree.afficher(flux) ; // <- Changement ici
return flux;
}
```

-code of the method:

```
void Duree::afficher(ostream &flux) const
{
flux << m_heures << "h" << m_minutes << "m" << m_secondes << "s";
}
```

But the problem is that when I compile I am told that "ostream is not a type name", "ostream was not declared in this code".
I don't understand, yet I searched the internet and apparently this is the right thing to do. I am using version 20.3 of Code :: Blocks.

Comment: Have you `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: yes , I did it.

Comment: Did you `#include <iostream>` and are you `using namespace std`? Or you need to write `std::ostream`

Comment: Pop a `std::` on the front to see if explicit naming solves the problem. If it doesn't we're gonna need a [mre] to help you out.

Comment: @Gouneken If we took the code you posted as-is, we would get many errors.   Compiler errors must be accompanied by the *exact* code that is being compiled, otherwise we are guessing what the issue is. [This compiles with no errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dbc8367b35105ff).  Take that code, change it to duplicate the error you're seeing.

Comment: Make the `ostream` function a `friend` of your `Duree` class.

Comment: Thanks but I found the solution the problem was that the function had to be in the main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work the function must be in the main file and not in the class file.